# Change an attribute on a Factory after creation of record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

Using FactoryBot, I'm having trouble creating a admin Factory in my specs because every user is assigned a default role of user in a `before_create` callback. This means that any role I assign a factory will be changed to user when the callback happens.

What I really want to do is something like this:

Inside my spec

```
admin = FactoryBot.create(:user)
admin.role = 'admin'
```

The second line, `admin.role = 'admin'` doesn't do anything. Any ideas?

I'm open to better ways of doing this as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just another way

```
# Steal some code from MrYoshiji at first.
factory :user do
  sequence(:username) { |n| "User ##{n}"}
  role 'user'  

  # Then a separate factory inside
  factory :admin do
    role 'admin'
  end
end

# Use
FactoryBot.create(:admin)
```

Comment: Wow is it possible to define a factory inside a factory?! FACTORYception! But what's the difference with a `trait`?

Comment: @MrYoshiji, yes it's possible :) I do that often.

Comment: The difference is you can use `create :admin` directly instead of `create :user, :admin`

Comment: The problem is that I'm assigning the role in a `before_create` in my User model, so wont specifying the role in the factory itself just get overwritten when the actual record is created?

Comment: @Arel, if you set role like this: `def set_role; self.role ||= 'user'; end` You won't have problem.

Comment: Ok, I'm trying it out now.

Comment: That worked!! Thank you! I have a question though. With it set up like this, there is no way someone could fill out the user registration form and pass an extra parameter for `user[role]= 'admin'`?

Comment: @Arel actually yes, if the user add an extra param role equal to admin, this user will be admin.

Comment: Ohh, well how do I prevent users from doing that?

Comment: @Arel, nice question! There do have a security hole. The solution I can think about is to delete such param attr in controller, like `def create; params[:user].delete![:role]; super #if using Devise; end;`

Comment: @Arel You can't, you have to force the role to be 'user' and only set the role to 'admin' manually after. So in your test cases, it would be an after(:create) callback -- in your application, it would be via rails console / seed / interface (link), but no form!

Comment: I don't know if @BillyChan solution would work, but instead I used @MrYoshiji solution of using an `after(:create)` callback in the admin block in the Factory. Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: I also agree with @MrYoshiji point. It's better to use callback for this specific case of admin factory

Answer (score 5):

There might be a way of reassigning the value to a FactoryBot (formerly FactoryGirl) instantiation, but RSpec negates the need:

```
describe User do
  let(:user) { FactoryBot.create(:user) }

  context 'when admin' do
    let(:user) { FactoryBot.create(:user, admin: true) }

    # ...
  end
end
```

Comment: The problem is that I'm assigning the role in a `before_create` in my User model, so won't assigning the role in `FactoryGirl.create just get overwritten when the record is actually created?

Answer (score 4):

Try using a `trait`:

```
factory :user do
  sequence(:username) { |n| "User ##{n}"}
  role 'user'  

  trait :is_admin do
    role 'admin'
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
FactoryBot.create(:user, :is_admin)
```

---

Or eventually an `after(:create)`:

```
factory :user do
  sequence(:username) { |n| "user ##{n}"}
  role 'user'  
end

factory :user_admin, class: User do
  after(:create) { |user| user.role = 'admin'; user.save } # don't know if the .save is necessary here
  sequence(:username) { |n| "User Admin ##{n}"}
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `admin.role = 'admin'`, maybe you can try using `update_column` method. Example:

```
admin = FactoryBot.create(:user)
admin.update_column(:role, 'admin')
```

This solution worked for me.